# Update GMail "multiple inbox" programatically

Tags: python, gmail

In the GMail desktop user interface, Settings | Inbox tab, there is an "Inbox Type" option, with a "Multiple Inbox" choice. If selected, the user can specify up to 5 additional sections, each with a search and label, which will be displayed alongside the inbox.

I'm able to connect using the [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and execute searches - but I want to be able to adjust the multiple inbox settings on the account programatically.

If this isn't possible through a python program, what are my other options?